# Java Editor in Eclipse is acting like a plain text editor

Tags: java, eclipse

Java editor is not working on my eclipse.

- Ctrl + Space does not suggest anymore
- No more color coding (for classes, interfaces, methods, imports , etc.) is no longer present.
- Ctrl + Click to redirect to class being instantiated in not working.
  It looks like its working like a plain text editor.

[image]

I have also noticed that the J icon before the class name has been replaced by what looks like text editor icon. I tried to reset perspective but it hasn't made a difference,

Comment: What does the 'Resource' page of the Properties dialog for the file say the file 'Type' is?

Comment: Do you talk about the editor icon or the file icon? For the editor icon see answer below. Otherwise, please show a screenshot also containing the _Project Explorer_ or the _Package Explorer_ with that file.

Answer (score 1):

- You may be opening the file in text editor mode
- Try opening in Java Editor mode by right clicking on the file as shown in the below image

[image]

- Once done, syntax highlighting should work as shown below

[image]

Comment: That doesn't explain the icon not being the J icon for a Java file.

Comment: @greg-449 This depends on which icon was meant in the question, the editor icon or the file icon. Unfortunately the screenshot is cropped so that only the editor icon is visible. Therefore, and because the question does not mention the word _file_, I assume that this answer is correct.